# JavaScript: out of scope variable leads to an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope, var

A rather primitive question, but I can't find how to solve it:

I have an array initiated and in this scope and I need to push an object from a JSON (which got transformed from a XML) into a data array, which collects the data in a loop and I need to only then return the response out of scope, because in the scope it is not full yet.

How do I solve this rather primitive problem?

My minimal example looks like this:

```
{
...
dataarr.push(jsonObj['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns:Response']['return']['items']);
} // scope 1 ends here
res.status(200).send(dataarr); // out of scope in this scope 2 the response has to be sent back to the client
```

I get the error because the variable is out of scope, how do I fix this though?

**UPDATE 1**

More code:

```
let dataarr = [];

let payloadarr = [];
...
axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
 logger.log('info', 'POST /getdata successful from ' + req.ip);
 var options = {
   attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
   attrNodeName: "attr", //default is 'false'
   textNodeName : "#text",
   ignoreAttributes : true,
   ignoreNameSpace : false,
   allowBooleanAttributes : false,
   parseNodeValue : true,
   parseAttributeValue : false,
   trimValues: true,
   cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
   cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
   parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
   arrayMode: false, //"strict"
   attrValueProcessor: (val, attrName) => he.decode(val, {isAttributeValue: true}),//default is a=>a
   tagValueProcessor : (val, tagName) => he.decode(val), //default is a=>a
   stopNodes: ["parse-me-as-string"]
 };
 console.log("response.data:");
 console.log(response.data);
 if( parser.validate(response.data) === true) { //optional (it'll return an object in case it's not valid)
 var jsonObj = parser.parse(response.data,options);
}

var tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(response.data,options);
var jsonObj = parser.convertToJson(tObj,options);
console.log("jsonObj in parsing:");
console.log(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonObj['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns:getResponse']['return']['items']);
dataarr.push(jsonObj['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns:getResponse']['return']['items']);
console.log("dataarr getting filled:");
console.log(j);
console.log(dataarr);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  logger.warn('[/getdocumentmetadata]: ', new Error(error));
  //console.log(error);
});
}
})
.catch(function (error) {
  logger.warn('[GET /getdocuments]: ', new Error(error));
});
res.status(200).send(dataarr);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it. You can either use `await` to wait for each result or you can use `Promise.all` to run them asynchronously and wait for the final result.

*Option 1*

```
let dataArr = [];
for(...){
    const myData= await axios(config).then(res => {
         var jsonObject = parse(res);
         return jsonObject;
    }).catch(...);
    dataArr.push(myData)
}
res.status(200).send(dataArr);
```

*Option 2*

```
let promises = [];
for(){
    promises.push(axios(config).then(res => {
        var jsonObject= parse(res);
        return jsonObject;
    })
    .catch(...));
}
let dataArr = await Promise.all(promises);
res.status(200).send(dataArr);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! (tried Option 2)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1**

You don't await the axios call so the function is resolved before you filled dataarr.

```js
let dataarr = [] // at the top of you function

...
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    ...
    resolve()
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
  ...
```

Could you try with this ?

Comment: That is apparently already the case as I see it, but I will add some code to check it. The problem is that the code is like 200+ overwhelming lines of code, so I will add only the relevant parts.

Comment: Updated the question ^^

Comment: And to answer your question - there's not a if condition, but rather a for loop..

Comment: Is see a lot of "catch", are you sure that the `let dataarr` is out of all the intermediates scopes ?

Comment: Maybe the error lies in the fact that there are too many `catch` statements?..

Comment: No, I wonder if the `let array` isn't declared in a `try` and should be done before, did you try to move the `dataarr` declaration at the top of the function ?

Comment: I did try that, then the response is simply `[]`. Now if I move the `dataarr` definition below it throws a `ReferenceError: datarr is not defined` error...

Comment: When you mode it at the top, did you delete the previous declaration ? Because js accept
```js
function sample() {
  let data = []
  try {
    let data = []
    data.push(1)
    console.log(data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  // second
  console.log(data)
}
```
first log => [1]
second log => []

Comment: I commented it out below then, yes..

Comment: And are you sure the push was called ?

Comment: You think the `push` is out of scope itself or what exactly?

Comment: Is this `console.log(dataarr);` logging a non-empty array ?

Comment: Yes it logs the JSON Array containing one member only, because of the scope. That's where initially the `res.status(200).send...` function resided as well initially but it would only get partial data then

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: You were on the right track, but the accepted answer had more options to choose from, sorry. I did upvote you though, you did help me

Comment: No problem, he did a good job ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the top the response variable is called "response" and in the last line its suddenly "res". I see no deklaration for the variable called "res".

Are these two different variables or unfortunated copied code?

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, within the scope of the `then` statement you can see that I use the `response` instead of `res`. Outside I use `res`, which is correct Express.js syntax.

Comment: I still think the res variable is out of scope. Also this line seems off for me (almost at the end):


`});
}
})
.catch...`

what are you catching there? When i copy your code, the brackets don't add up.

Comment: I made this endpoint when I added two separate endpoints together, so the two catch statements might be very bad for me, you're right on that point. The brackets don't add up, because I for brevity removed them at the start of the endpoint... The full endpoint code is like 200+ lines of code which is an overkill for StackOverflow...

Comment: I was afraid that could be the case. I hoped for an easy answer. Sometimes we oversee the most obvious. Good luck with further debugging!